# Compare FileTime and LocalDateTime

Tags: java

How to compare [FileTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html) and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects in Java?

I want to compare a FileTime object from a file (`Files.getLastModifiedTime(item)`) with the current time (`LocalDateTime.now()`). But they are not compatible. How can I compare them?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get instant from FileTime and create a LocalDateTime object using the instant.

Example

```
FileTime fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(item);
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime convertedFileTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(fileTime.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Now you can compare now & convertedFileTime.

Remember this is not taking into consideration the timezones which can change.

You can just work with `Instant` as well.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it replies what the OP asked for.

Comment: But I don't have 233k reps... :)

Comment: That's true. For my problem the way using `Instant` is better. But for my specific question here this is the answer. I will correct it.

Answer (score 9):

The `FileTime` API is designed to encourage you to use `Instant` rather than `LocalDateTime`:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
FileTime ft = Files.getLastModifiedTime(item);

if (ft.toInstant().isAfter(now)) { ... }
```

Note that `Instant` makes  more sense than `LocalDateTime` in this case because it represents a *unique* instant "in real life". Whereas a `LocalDateTime` can be ambiguous, for example during Daylight Saving Time changes.

Comment: FileTime class doesn't have isAfter method.

Comment: @Sneh Thanks, I forgot the `toInstant` bit.

Comment: I actually can not test the implementation but it looks like this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

My practice when dealing with times, dates, time zones, etc... I usually convert those objects into Unix timestamp and then do needed operations.

```
long lastModifiedFileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(item).toMillis()/1000;
long now = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

this would do it, but maybe you should consider using Instant instead of LocalDateTime, stuff gets overly complicated when dealing with time zones(depending on your requirements ofc).

```
long now = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

Also you can use Instant objects

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
Instant lastModifiedFileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime().toInstant();
```

Answer (score 0):

These are different time structures. You could use `toInstant` methods to convert them the same type. But LocalDateTime would require timezone. I guess that you just need current system clock time, so instead of `LocalDateTime.now()` you should use `Clock.systemUTC().instant()`, so you don't need to convert.

Moreover, if you inject Clock into your code, it will be much easier to mock from unit-tests rather than have dependency on a static methods which give you system time.